# An 'if' issue ( min 15 characters in this site...)

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    int seats,passengers,quad,single;
    double tickprice;

    System.out.println ("enter number of passengers, seats in plane and price of a single ticket:");

    passengers = reader.nextInt();
    seats = reader.nextInt();
    tickprice = reader.nextInt();

    if (passengers!=seats) {
        System.out.println ("no empty seats in the plane");
    } else { 
        if (passengers < seats) {
            System.out.println ("there are empty seats in the plane");
        }
    }
}
```

This is just the beginning of a question I got in class, I wanted to check this part after I finished it to see if it works and it doesnt, I dont get any message after writing the the number of seats and number of passengers, why is that? is it because of the if brackets? because I deleted and changed them a few times

Comment: should be == not !=

Comment: oh ok, I forgot that for some reason

Comment: please keep more focus at the question and the problems and try to format your question/code little bit better.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't fundamentally change what you're asking in a question post, especially not if it already has answers and comments - it's best to separate different questions into different question posts.

Comment: I cant separate the questions because this site doesnt let me ask more than 1 question every 48 hours or something like that and I have a test tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ask the correct questions, you won't get the correct answers.

You need to input 2 valid numbers here:

```
 passengers = reader.nextInt();
 seats = reader.nextInt();
```

So they have a truth value in either of these statements.

```
 if (passengers!=seats) 
 if (passengers < seats)
```

On another note, passengers!=seats doesn't make sense.

When the passengers number is different than the number of seats it doesn't mean there isn't enough seats available

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check to make sure passengers are not greater than or equal to the number of seats in the plane.

if (passengers!=seats) { should be if (passengers >= seats) {

Another quick note for the else and if. Your first if statement will check to make sure the passengers aren't greater than or equal to the number of seats. If that expression evaluates to false, you'll then know passengers is less than seats, so you can replace your else if with just an else since you already know passengers is less than seats:

} else {

```
System.out.println ("there are empty seats in the plane");
```

}